# Why does running pwck show so many directories don't exist?

Tags: users, home-directory

I ran the pwck command in an Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit VM. The output was that the directories for many users do not exist:

[image: pwck output]

I see that there are many users without a directory, and most of them look like system users. I get why /nonexistent doesn't exist, but what about the others? Should I be adding them?

Answer (score 1):

Each of these userids is used for owning server processes, and NEVER logs in interactively. Therefore, no need for a `$HOME` directory. You'll also notice that these userids have strange shells, like `/bin/false`. Read `man 5 passwd`

Comment: So first, I should check if it's shell isn't /bin/false or /usr/sbin/nologin, then I should add the directory? Thanks!

Comment: You should NOT create the home directories - they're unneeded, and, aside from shutting up `pwck`, have no use, and creating them can open security holes.

Comment: I meant that if I check those users in /etc/passwd and the shell is not /usr/sbin/nologin or /bin/false, then I need to add the home directory or change the shell, is that correct?

Comment: `pwck` documents the security model it uses in `man pwck`. This is NOT the security model used by Ubuntu. By messing with your system to make `pwck` happy, you WILL break Ubuntu's security model.

Comment: Do you know of a better alternate for Ubuntu? I tried searching it up to no avail.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This is evolving into an XY question.

Comment: *a slightly wiser self returns to this answer*
I was trying to figure out if any users were not setup properly or possibly maliciously. I just check this manually now.

Comment: There are many "security vulnerability scanners", some of which may be more suited to your needs. You could encapsulate your manual checks in a script (`bash`, `perl`, ....). But, none of the checks is worth doing until you understand how Ubuntu works. Blindly "fixing" things will break something, which may "fail open" or "fail closed".